# Use python regex to split a string column to create new columns of a data frame in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I need to extract the last part of a string within a series to create new series(columns) in my dataframe. Below is the string column example

| Joke_identifier |
| --- |
| Klint De Drunk Enugu 1 |
| Klint De Drunk Enugu 2 |
| Klint De Drunk Enugu 3 |
| Gordons Lagos 1 |
| Gordons Lagos 2 |

I tried using this line of code to extract the last part of the string

```
import re

train_data.Joke_identifier.str.split(r"[a-zA-Z]\s[0-9]\Z", expand=True)
```

But it returns
`Klint De Drunk Enug`

I would get a new data frame as shown below

| Joke_identifier | Joker | City | Edition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Klint De Drunk Enugu 1 | Klint De Drunk | Enugu | 1 |
| Klint De Drunk Enugu 2 | Klint De Drunk | Enugu | 2 |
| Klint De Drunk Enugu 3 | Klint De Drunk | Enugu | 3 |
| Gordons Lagos 1 | Gordons | Lagos | 1 |
| Gordons Lagos 2 | Gordons | Lagos | 2 |

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.extract`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Joke_identifier':['Klint De Drunk Enugu 1', 'Klint De Drunk Enugu 2', 'Klint De Drunk Enugu 3', 'Gordons Lagos 1','Gordons Lagos 2']})
df[['Joker','City','Edition']] = df['Joke_identifier'].str.extract(r"^(.*)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)$", expand=True)
df
#            Joke_identifier           Joker   City Edition
#  0  Klint De Drunk Enugu 1  Klint De Drunk  Enugu       1
#  1  Klint De Drunk Enugu 2  Klint De Drunk  Enugu       2
#  2  Klint De Drunk Enugu 3  Klint De Drunk  Enugu       3
#  3         Gordons Lagos 1         Gordons  Lagos       1
#  4         Gordons Lagos 2         Gordons  Lagos       2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olAVmA/1).

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1 (Column "Joker"): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 2 (Column "City"): any one or more whitespaces
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 3 (Column "Edition"): one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.